# VO2 unexpected conduction

Tags: conductivity, thermal-conductivity

$\ce{VO2}$ is a weird metal which becomes a conductor at temperatures higher than $\pu{67 ^\circ C}$, but below $\pu{67 ^\circ C}$, it is an insulator!

How is this possible anyway? This is against solid state theory and how are we supposed to create band gaps with it?

Comment: VO2 is not a metal. it is a metal oxide

Comment: Metal and Metal Oxide are not mutually exclusive. VO and VO2 both have metallic phases, for instance.

Comment: Metal-insulator transitions are well known in solid state physics. They occur for various reasons. Yes, it is a little weird the first time you encounter one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really the same vanadium dioxide.  The 67°C temperature corresponds to a [phase change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanadium(IV)_oxide).  Compare with the phase change in solid [tin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin).